# How to intercept the 'set' function in Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

With regular getter/setters you can do something like this

```
function setRating (num) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = 10;

    var result = num;

    if      (num < min)   result = min;
    else if (num > max)   result = max;

    this.rating = result;
}

setRating(20);  //rating == 10
```

With Backbone though you'd call something like `movie.set('rating', 20);`.

How could I intercept that function to place in my little logic?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Backbone, but couldn't you have an event listener that fires this function on "change:rating"?

Comment: You might want to listen to change:rating on the model. If the incoming value passes your validation or whatever, then you can set it. If not, you can rollback the value with the previous attributes stuff that Backbone provides.

Comment: @JamesBruckner: No, that won't work, an event handler can't stop the change from happening or alter anything (at least not without chicanery); you can also have ordering problems if there are other event listeners, I don't think there is any particular guaranteed order for when event listeners will be called. The OP wants to clean up the rating *before* Backbone gets its hands on it.

Comment: @CoryDanielson the problem with that, is that would pollute the event space, with a bunch of `change` events. It also means I can't use `option.silent`

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was trying to think of a way of getting around overriding set because I didn't want to write up a demo in js fiddle... lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide your own implementation of [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) that cleans up incoming values before handing them off to the standard `set`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
set: function(key, val, options) {
    // This first bit is what `set` does internally to deal with
    // the two possible argument formats.
    var attrs;
    if(typeof key === 'object') {
        attrs = key;
        options = val;
    }
    else {
        (attrs = {})[key] = val;
    }

    // Clean up the incoming key/value pairs.
    this._clean_up(attrs);

    // And then punt to the standard Model#set
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);
},
_clean_up: function(attributes) {
    if('rating' in attributes) {
        // Force the rating into the desired range...
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Gm3xD/2/

Comment: Boy that thing is hideous, but it's the only thing I could think of either. Always a pleasure mu :D

Comment: Yeah. a bit hideous but most of the nastiness is a side effect of having to deal with `set(x, y)` vs `set(obj)`. You could hide the nastiness by monkey patching that right into `Backbone.Model`, you'd just need to grab a reference to `Backbone.Model.prototype.set` first and call that reference instead of doing `Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(...)`.